# Inline all the functions in C code with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, inline

I have many C programs without recursion.
I want to get the program without user-defined function but the main function.
GCC can do the [inline](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) but that's in IR level so I can't get C code .

SOURCE:

```
int calc(int a , int b)
{
    a=a+b-2;
    return a ;
}

int main()
{
    int x=4,y=7;
    x=calc(x,y);
    return 0 ;
}
```

TARGET:

```
int main()
{
    int x=4,y=7;
    int calc_A=x,calc_B=y;
    calc_A=calc_A+calc_B-2;
    x=calc_A;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `inline` is just a suggestion to a compiler , compiler may ignore it.. What do you exactly want ? , please little elaborte

Comment: I've edited my question again.

Comment: Are you trying to generate new source code where every function call is replaced by its corresponding source code or do you want binary optimization where its the resulting executable that should be inlined?

Comment: did you ever found an answer to your question?

Comment: @iomartin No. I did it without the GCC.

Comment: @ZhangLongQI do you mean you did it manually? Or did you use some other tool?

Comment: @iomartin Manually

Answer (score 0):

There is a function attribute provided by gcc, called [`always_inline`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Usage:

```
int add(int arg1, int arg2)__attribute__((always_inline)); // prototype
int add(int arg1, int arg2){
    return arg1+arg2;
}
```

However, you would have to manually attach this attribute to every function.

I am still *assuming* that all your functions follow rules which are necessary to be inlined. e.g. no goto, recursion, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It doesn't match my question.

Comment: @ZhangLongQI if it doesn't answer your question, then you should not accept the answer