# Inline all functions and get C code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, inline

Is there a tool that takes a C source file as input, inlines all functions and outputs another C source file?

All functions are contained in one single file and there are no recursions/gotos. Functions do not necessarily have the `inline` attribute.

It is OK (and actually desirable) if this tool ignores functions declared in standard libraries (such as `printf`, `malloc` and `sqrt`).

Related question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970806/inline-all-the-functions-in-c-code-with-gcc/13970971#13970971): the only answer is incorrect.

Comment: The only answer is incorrect how!? That GCC specific attribute does as advertised.

Comment: It's not wrong, it just doesn't do what this question is asking (because they're totally different questions).

Comment: IMO it is either impossible or meaningless: inlining works because there is no argument passing needed, and because variables are shared between caller and callee. This process depends on (register-)allocation, which is compiler- and architecture dependent. For example: Imagine what would happen if you *inlined* on a machine with 32 registers, and compiled the preprocessed code on a machine with fewer: register-trashing would be the result.

Comment: This is not a simple preprocessing transformation, because standard C does not have an expression construction which can accommodate local variables. Nor can you easily express control flow within an expression. You could try using clang or some other compiler library to produce an internal representation of the inlined code and then attempt to recreate C code from that, but it will be a lot of work and the results won't be particularly readable. Perhaps this is an X-Y problem and you need to ask a more direct question about what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

That won't help you. At least for gcc the inlining happens after the textual source code has been transformed into the internal representation.

You can take a look at this:

```
int x;

__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void foobar () { x--; }

int main() {
    x = 1;
    foobar (); 
    return x;
}
```

Calling `g++ example.cpp -O0 -g -E` on this will result in:

```
✓ pan:~$ g++ example.cpp -O0 -g -E
# 1 "example.cpp"
# 1 "/home/meyer//"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "example.cpp"
int x;

__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void foobar () { x--; }

int main() {
    x = 1;
    foobar ();
    return x;
}
```

but when compiling with `g++ example.cpp -O0 -g -o example.elf`, the resulting executable will not have a function `foobar` anymore. You can check with `objdump -w | less`, and compare to omitting the attribute.

I used `-O0` to prevent any optimizations from happening, since most compilers should be smart enough to figure out that the function can be trivially optimized to a `int main () { return 0; }`.

I don't know if there is a tool for what you try to do out there. But I'm afraid you need a full C++-aware lexer/parser-combination for a C++-to-C++-cross-compiler to do this correctly in all cases.